# CSS vertical & horizontal align, regardless of screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm using a lovely little free open source slider on my site, however in different browsers and resolutions the images inside don't sit flush to my top and bottom borders.  To correct this, I've tried using larger images so there's always something on display.  Thing is, I need the images to be forced to sit in the centre from the centre of any resolution - you know what I mean?  I need it to read the alignment from the centre of the image...

Hope that makes sense, the website can be seen live at youthenterprise.co.uk/coded/bank.php (the images there make it more obvious what I'm trying to achieve) and here's the script and code:

```
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
</script>
<div id="slider">
        <ul class="bxslider">
         <li><a href="funding.php"> <img src="images/slides/funding.gif" alt="01" border="0" /></a></li>
         <li><a href="case.php"><img src="images/slides/case.gif" alt="02"border="0" /></a></li>
         <li><a href="start.php"> <img src="images/slides/start.gif" alt="03" border="0" /></a></li>
         <li><a href="resources.php"> <img src="images/slides/resources.gif" alt="04" border="0" /></a></li>
         <li><a href="links.php"> <img src="images/slides/links.gif" alt="05" border="0"/></a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.php"> <img src="images/slides/contact.gif" alt="06" border="0"/></a></li>
  </ul>


</div><!--slider close-->
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    background:url(images/slider_divider.gif) 0 bottom repeat-x;
    height: 255px;
    border: none;
    text decoration: none;
    z-index: 0;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.bx-wrapper img {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    alignment-adjust:central; !important
    zoom: 1;
    *width: 2000px;
    *margin-left: -100px;
    *padding-left: 60px;
    *margin-top: -70px;
}



.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    height: 249px !important; //provide height of slider
    max-width: 2000px;
    min-width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;



    /*fix other elements on the page moving (on Chrome)*/
    -webkit-transform: translatez(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
        -ms-transform: translatez(0);
        -o-transform: translatez(0);
        transform: translatez(0);
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-pager,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I appreciate any help anyone can give, even if it's just to say it can't be done!

Also, it needs to be IE7 compatible, the people who have asked me to do it only have access to very old equipment (old XP machines with IE7 and 800px resolution!)

Comment: Are these images different sizes?

Comment: " images inside don't sit flush to my top and bottom borders." - Care to provide a visual representation of 1)what you have, and 2) what you want to achieve? (those being very specific related to your request please). Your website address didn't help me trying to understand what exactly do you need... Thanks.

Comment: provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem and explain it with as much details as you can

Comment: align vertically with css is pretty dificult since every browser considers the end of the document in a diferent way.
to get full screen heigth you have to aply 100% to de document body and html tags.
and probably that will not work in zombie browsers

Comment: The images will all be the same size, I've changed the first 3 to the size that they will be to try to get it to work.  I'll try to get some screen grabs of the issues I'm having with it not sitting flush to the borders.

Comment: I'm not sure what a JSFiddle is?  What do I do with that link?

Comment: Okay screengrabs:

What I want it to look like: youthenterprise.co.uk/coded/example.gif
How it looks in Chrome: youthenterprise.co.uk/coded/chrome.gif
How it looks in IE7: youthenterprise.co.uk/coded/IE7.gif